# how can i put the username in the navbar after logging in?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i want to put the username in the navbar after logging it happens , i am using jwt for authentication and everything is just fine

the profile file , i use decode to decrypt the jwt token and compare it with the users one , it gives me his data in the best way possible , i tried to do such in the landing page including navbar , i tried to put in componentDidMount but it is not a good way since the moment the site loads , the token isnt found yet , thus it crashes
what shall i do to put it in the navbar

my landing page that contains the navbar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


class Landing extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username:''
    }
  }


  logOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.props.history.push(`/`)
  }

  render() {
    const currentuser= localStorage.usertoken
    const loginRegLink = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
            Login
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">
            Register
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )

    const userLink = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
            User
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
            Logout
          </a>
        </li >

      </ul>
    )

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark rounded">
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarsExample10"
          aria-controls="navbarsExample10"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>

        <div
          className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center"
          id="navbarsExample10"
        >
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {localStorage.usertoken ? userLink : loginRegLink}
        </div>

      </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Landing)
```

react App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./components/user/Signup";
import Login from "./components/user/Login";
import Navbar from './components/user/Navbar'
import Landing from './components/user/Landing'
import Profile from './components/user/Profile'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
          <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />

        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>


          </Switch>
        </div>

      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}



export default App
```

the profile file where i decode and show the data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username:'',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      errors: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
    this.setState({
      username:decoded.username,
      first_name: decoded.first_name,
      last_name: decoded.last_name,
      email: decoded.email
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="container">
        <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
          <div className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
            <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
          </div>
          <table className="table col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>{this.state.first_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>{this.state.last_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>{this.state.email}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Profile
```

the controllers where i do signup , login and profile

```
//express requirement
const express = require('express')
//setting a users variable to be used as a router instead of app post , get ..
const users = express.Router()
//cross oigin resource sharing 
const cors = require('cors')
//jwt for user login authentication
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
//bcrypt for password encryption and decryption
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//using te user model
const User = require('../model/user')
//setting users as cros origin functionalities
users.use(cors())
//privat key or jwt encryption and decryption
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1'

//main signup function , exported
users.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  //setting a new user object to be manipulated and inserted to db 
  //data taken from react client side 
  const today = new Date()
  const userData = {
    username : req.body.username,
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

  //a function from sequelize , a wrapper for later on functions
  //searches if the username is found or not 
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      //searching in the whhole db for this user name 
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
    // encrypting the password using bcrypt encryption function
    //bcrypt uses a hash function to encrypt the user given password
    //will not reach this part if user is duplicated
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        //hashing the password , 10 is a number for permutations 2pwr10 = a certain string built in
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash
          //creating a user with the given data
          User.create(userData)
          //send the username to the response tab in console
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.username + '    '+ 'Registered!' })
            })
            //any error will be consoled here
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err)
            })
        })
      } else {
        //will reach if username is found ,  User.findOne 
        res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

//main login functionality
users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  ///searches for username in db at first
  User.findOne({
    where: {
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
  //if the user is found , it compared the password with the given password
  //it compared it the encrypted pass in the db
  //and decrypts it to compare
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        //if user name is found the deryption starts here
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          //each user is given a certain jwt token for authentication
          //jwt.sign , Synchronously sign the given payload into a JSON Web Token string payload
          //secret key provided above
          //token is assigned using the front end whuck sends it with the request
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          })
          //send token to local storage of the browser that checks it 
          res.send(token)
        }
      } else {
        //reaches here if user isnt found
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
      }
    })
    //catches any error from the above blocks
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    })
})

users.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  //Synchronously verify given token using a secret or a public key to get a decoded token token -
  // JWT string to verify secretOrPublicKey - Either the secret for HMAC algorithms, 
  //or the PEM encoded public key for RSA and ECDSA.
  // [options] - Options for the verification returns - The decoded token.
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY)


  //searches for user
  User.findOne({
    //decode user id and jwt 
    where: {
      id: decoded.id

    }

  })
  //if true, user is sent as a json object to browser
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        res.json(user)
      } else {
        //if false , send this response
        res.send('User does not exist')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

my endpoints for login and signup

```
import axios from 'axios'

//the signup endpoint sent from front end and interpreted by the browser
//route is an api called users , exported from server side
//posting user data as in server
//sending a response if true
export const signup = newUser => {
  return axios
    .post('users/signup', {
      username : newUser.username,
      first_name: newUser.first_name,
      last_name: newUser.last_name,
      email: newUser.email,
      password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Registered')
    })
}

//login end point
//using username and password , using the decoded id 
export const login = async user => {
  try {
    const response = await axios
      .post('users/login', {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
      });
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
    return response.data;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `render` props?

Comment: As you are already setting localStorage, you can do this where you want to show username, const usertoken = localStorage.getItem('usertoken'); {usertoken ? usertoken.username : null}

Comment: @ravibagul91 can i put it in the navbar page as you written?

Comment: @sk01 no not really can you tell me how ?

Comment: @GhadikhaledMdallal Yes you can do so.

Comment: @ravibagul91 didnt work bro

Comment: @ravibagul91 it worked but presented the wholejwt token a huge string not the username

Comment: the navbar items + eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ikp..................

Comment: post your `localStorage.getItem('usertoken')` token here.

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZ2hhZGltZCIsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJnaGFkaSIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6Im1kIiwiZW1haWwiOiJnaGFkaWlpaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCQucGpULlFGcTN6SnJwNW1USzdqekNPdUdtUWY0aTB6Vi40UDBsNS5YQlIzQldDckpFU2paUyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDE5LTA3LTA4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTYyNjU1MzAyLCJleHAiOjE1NjI2NTY3NDJ9._iiLvVEy4aWb1iyzXSJ0zFGZHHj3CVPC3q_l12u2plU

Comment: parseJwt(token) {
    if (!token) { return; }
    const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
}

Comment: this function is returning me the jwt token parsed and each variable alone

Comment: but the main problem is that i want it after user is logged in , it is failing because it is not getting any toen expet post login request , it crashed for not finding the genrerated token , so it should be done at login but how to add the username to the navbar after login

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to lift the state up. You can define state in `App` component and then can pass data to the child components.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      errors: {}
    }
  }

  setUserProfile = () => {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
    this.setState({
      username: decoded.username,
      first_name: decoded.first_name,
      last_name: decoded.last_name,
      email: decoded.email
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar username={this.state.username} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" render={(props) =>
              <Profile
                {...props}
                {...this.state}
                setUserProfile={this.setUserProfile}
              />
            }
            />

            <Route path="/signup" render={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/login" render={Login} />


          </Switch>
        </div>

      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}


class Profile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setUserProfile();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
          <div className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
            <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
          </div>
          <table className="table col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>{this.props.first_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>{this.props.last_name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>{this.props.email}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Profile
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (App.js:62)

Comment: it is because of render instead of component and the eexport type , isnt there any other way ? the App.js wil contain 100 routes in the future

Comment: `render` is used instead of `component` because `component` will result will in unmounting and mounting of the component. I just googled the error you are getting. Have you imported React and Component at top?

Comment: bro you didnt export App why ?

Comment: export it. I just pasted the changed code. It is not all.

Comment: btw i want to sow the username throught the app not just progfile later on

Comment: then you will need to pass `state` to every component.

Comment: same error bro App.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: paste your whole App.js

Comment: i pasted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter , Switch , Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import Navbar from './components/user/Navbar'
import Landing from './components/user/Landing'
import Login from './components/user/Login'
import SignUp from './components/user/Signup'
import Profile from './components/user/Profile'


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        username: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        errors: {}
      }
    }

    setUserProfile = () => {
      const token = localStorage.usertoken
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
      this.setState({
        username: decoded.username,
        first_name: decoded.first_name,
        last_name: decoded.last_name,
        email: decoded.email
      })
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar username={this.state.username} />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={Landing} />
              <Route exact path="/profile" render={(props) =>
                <Profile
                  {...props}
                  {...this.state}
                  setUserProfile={this.setUserProfile}
                />
              }
              />

              <Route path="/signup" render={SignUp} />
              <Route path="/login" render={Login} />


            </Switch>
          </div>

        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
  }



export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. `render` props takes function(not the component).

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar username={this.state.username} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Landing />} />
      <Route exact path="/profile" render={(props) =>
        <Profile
          {...props}
          {...this.state}
          setUserProfile={this.setUserProfile}
        />
      }
      />
      <Route path="/signup" render={() => <SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```